# Kashering by Placing in a Self-Cleaning Oven

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, kashering-kosherization, appliances

I think I remember learning once that one can kasher something that requires libun (e.g. a pan or cookie tray) by cleaning it and putting it in a self-ceaning oven. Is this true? If so, it sounds much easier than using a blowtorch.

Comment: The halachos for ashkanazim and sefardim are different

Comment: Make sure the item in question can take the heat of the self-cleaning cycle.

Comment: If you do this, and there is any residue left in the oven afterwards besides white ash, there is something wrong with your self-clean cycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the 2014 OU Jewish Action Passover Guide on page 14 under "Libun (Burning)"

On Line [THE KASHERING PRIMER – PASSOVER 2014](http://oukosher.org/passover/articles/kashering-for-passover/)

> A self-clean cycle of an oven(approx 850 degrees F) also qualifies as libun

I have done it but it can also mess up some utensils. I was also been given this advice by the Baltitimore star-k, when I called the office.